# How do I make keyframes stay when I draw another frame instead of the previous one to disappear

Tags: keyframes

In this stickman right here, I made his body hands and all, and now I want him to wave.

[image]

I need to make a new frame of his hand to make it look like he moved it until it loos like he is waving.

[image]

The whole painting is gone! The previous frame disappeared, leaving me with just a moving arm and an onionskin of the previous drawing

How do I make frames stay and just edit what I have to delete, add, move or even curve?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities and workflows, a couple of them:

- draw the body into one layer and the arms into another
- copy (Shift D) the previous keyframe into the next, erase the arms and draw the new ones
- go to the next keyframe and use edit mode and sculpt mode tools to move the arms.
- Create a rig for the arms and use bones to animate them.
- Go to next keyframe, press I to insert a duplicate of the active keyframe and draw and erase on it.